# Logstash filter Regex into Field

Tags: regex, filter, logstash

I am facing some issues with parsing a logline.

I Have thousends of loglines and every logline contains a hostname like ABC123DF 
I Have writen a regex and I want to apply it to the logline and put the hostname in the field "victim" Like this:

```
add_field => [ "victim", "/[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9].."
```

I have used the Mutate filter but the result is

victim      /[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]..

I would like to see:

victim     ABC123DF

how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need complex regex action to achieve this. You can use [several filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) to extract fields. In your case, the [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) is a good choice.

Let's suppose your **log lines** look like this:

```
20:20:20 ABC123DF 192.168.1.1
```

Then a **grok filter** like this would parse the hostname properly:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIME:timestamp} %{HOST:host} %{IP:srcip}" }
}
```

You can also use **regex inside grok** ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns)). Example Pattern:

```
%{GREEDYDATA} (?<host>.*) %{GREEDYDATA}
```

However, I would recommend to avoid regex in grok. It is a better approach to go with the included patterns. Use the [grok debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to find the right patterns for you.

Answer (score 2):

I user this site, http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result, to test my regex.

In my mongodb log, I have this text:

> 2016-05-17T16:26:07.018-0300 I QUERY    [conn50628097] getmore
>   dataBaseName.collectionName query: { empresa: "********" }
>   cursorid:443889850763 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0
>   numYields:69 nreturned:8886 reslen:1184746 locks:{ Global: {
>   acquireCount: { r: 140 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 70 },
>   acquireWaitCount: { r: 66 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 98046 } },
>   Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 70 } } } 178ms

For get query and time, in config file, I make this filter:

```
    filter {
      if [source] == "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" {
        grok {
          match=> {
            "message" => [
              "(getmore|query)\s(?<mongo_database>[a-zA-Z_]+)\.(?<mongo_collection>[a-zA-Z_.]+)\s?query:\s(?<mongo_query>\{.*?\})\s(cursorid|planSummary).*?\s(?<mongo_totaltime>[0-9]+ms)"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Use:

```
    (?<you_new_field_name>you_regex)you_regex(?<you_new_field_name>you_regex)(?<you_new_field_name>you_regex)
```

after this, you can make:

```
    add_field => [ "tag_text_optional%{you_new_field_name}", "%{you_new_field_name}" ]
```

Comment: Logstash use **oniguruma** for expreg https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE

Answer (score 0):

So in my case the logline is:

2015-10-20 14:45:42,156 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO audit Terminated abc123df from group LLDS2Cassandra [LOCAL] with NetworkCorruption

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIME:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL} %{VICTIM:victim} " }
}
```

And in the grok patterns I put the following line:
`VICTIM [a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

To get the following result:

FIELD: TIMESTAMP
VALUE: 2015-10-20 14:45:42,156

FIELD: VICTIM
VALUE: abc123df

FIELD:LOGLEVEL
VALUEE:INFO